# When is true that $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(xy)\ dx\ dy=\ -\int_0^1 \log(x) f(x)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Saw in a post this identity
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(xy)\ dx\ dy=\ -\int_0^1 \log(x) f(x)\ dx$$
then the author says "notice that $f$ is under some restrictions", and concludes the post, without saying what restrictions! I'd like to know what these restrictions are, since in the proof he provided I couldn't find any.

Here is the proof:

Let $xy=t$, so $dx=\frac{dt}{y}$, and the integral becomes:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^y f(t)\ \frac{dt}{y}\ dy$$=
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{y} \int_0^y f(t)\ dt\ dy$$
now integrate by parts with
$$u=\int_0^yf(t)\ dt\hspace{2cm} dv=\frac{1}{y}\ dy$$
and get
$$\left[\log(y)\int_0^yf(t)\ dt\right]_{y=0}^{y=1} -\int_0^1 \log(y) f(y)\ dy=$$
$$=\ 0\ -\ 0\ -\int_0^1 \log(y) f(y)\ dy=$$
$$=-\int_0^1 \log(y) f(y)\ dy$$
and the proof is concluded. Please help with the restrictions on $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, then no other restriction on $f$ is required in order that

$$\tag{*}\lim_{y \to 0+}\log(y) \int_0^y f(t) \, dt = 0$$

Since a Riemann integrable function is bounded, there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(t)| \leqslant M$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ and, hence, for all $y \in [0,1)$

$$0 \leqslant \left|\log(y) \int_0^y f(t) \, dt \right|= -\log(y)\left|\int_0^y f(t) \, dt\right|\leqslant -\log(y)\int_0^y|f(t)| \, dt\leqslant -My\log(y)$$

Since $\lim_{y \to 0+} y \log(y) = 0$, it follows from the squeeze theorem that  (*) holds.

---

If anything warrants concern it is the step $du = f(y) \,dy$ when $u = \int_0^y f(t) \,dt$. This is because $f$ need not be continuous at every point in $[0,1]$ when it is assumed only to be Riemann integrable. However, $f$ will be continuous almost everywhere and the integration by parts formula is still valid.

Comment: You wrote "Since a Riemann integrable function is bounded, there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(t)| \leqslant M$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ and, hence, for all $y \in [0,1)$". However, note that $f(t) = t^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is Riemann integrable (in particular, $\int_{0}^{y}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}dt = \left. 2t^{\frac{1}{2}}\right|_{0}^{y} = 2y^{\frac{1}{2}}$), but it *isn't* bounded, on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: All Riemann integrable functions must be bounded. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2250827/148510). Technically $x^{-1/2}$ has an improper Rieman integral.  Nevertheless, the actual identity holds for any Lebesgue integrable function but that is probably outside of the scope of the OP here.

Comment: See also this older [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/610054/148510) on the boundedness of Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what other requirements of $f$ if any beyond general integrability would be needed to ensure that the limit here is $0$.  With $f(t) = t^{-1/2}$ this reduces to $2 \sqrt{y} \log(y)$ which also converges to $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more general result:

> **Theorem.** Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Then
>
> $$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} f(xy) \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_{0}^{1} f(t)\log(1/t) \, \mathrm{d}t. \tag{*} $$
>
> holds whenever at least one of the integrals in $\text{(*)}$ is finite with $f$ replaced by either
>
> - the *positive part* of $f$, namely $f_+(t) = \max\{0, f(t)\}$, or
> - the *negative part* of $f$, namely $f_-(t) = \max\{0, -f(t)\}$.

*Proof.* Define the two Borel measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $[0, 1]$ by

$$ \mu(E) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{1}_{E}(xy) \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\nu(E) = \int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{1}_{E}(t)\log(1/t) \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

Then for $0 \leq a \leq 1$, a straightforward computation shows that

\begin{align*}
\mu([a, 1])
&= \int_{a}^{1}\int_{a/y}^{1} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
= 1 - a - a\log a
= \int_{a}^{1} \log(1/t) \, \mathrm{d}t
= \nu([a, 1]).
\end{align*}

Since the sets of the form $[a, 1]$, $0 \leq a \leq 1$, generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}([0, 1])$, it follows that $\mu = \nu$. Therefore the desired conclusion follows. $\square$

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the standard restriction that $f$ be integrable on $[0,1]$, another potential restriction on $f$ occurs where you used that

$$\left[\log(y)\int_0^y f(t)\,dt\right]_{y=0}^{y=1} = 0 - 0$$

In particular, there's a possible issue with

$$\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\log(y)\int_0^y f(t)\,dt\right) = 0$$

If $f(t)$ satisfies standard Riemann integrability, then the function is bounded in the range, so the limit above always applies (e.g., as explained in [RRL's answer](/a/4688624)). However, if $f(t)$ can be something like an improper Riemann integrable function, then the above limit may not hold  (e.g., where $\int_0^y f(t)\,dt = (-\log(y)+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$).

Comment: I believe if you assume $f$ to be Riemann integrable, then that limit is zero automatically.

Comment: I posted a general question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4688644/148510) if you want to take a stab at it.

Comment: Thank you. By identifying a potential problem with a seemingly innocuous limit you found something more interesting to think about.